# cannot join shapes as shape keys

Tags: mesh, shape-keys

[image]

I have two meshes that I've decimated to have the exact same number of vertices. but when i try to join them with shape keys I get this error

Comment: Some types of shape keys may have added vertices. Did the objects in question already have shape keys?

Comment: no, they did not

Comment: I'm guessing that error is a simplification of the requirements. If *only* the number of verts is the same, but the vert **indices** are jumbled so that `vertex x` on one mesh has connected edges but `vertex x` on the other mesh has no connected edges, or the edges are connected to *other* vertices, I can easily see that being a show-stopper. Shape Keys count on you providing the same fundamental topology, and then Shape Keys can deform from one set of vert positions to another. As soon as you run your mesh through a modifier like Decimate... well, look up the definition of "decimate". ;-)